# Linux Plasma 5.12.3 authorization failed on locked screen

Tags: linux, authentication, kde-plasma

I needed to install my OS (Sabayon, based on Gentoo with Kernel 4.15 and Plasma 5.12.3) again. Installation went fine so far. 
When I boot into login screen I can login normally with my password and the Plasma DE appears.

When I lock my screen, I see a wallpaper and a field to enter my password to unlock. Everything as known before.
But when I now try to enter my login password, the same like from first boot, I get a message, which says: "Authorization failed". This behavior is reproducible.

The only way to get back to my Plasma session is to open a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F2), login as root and enter the command:

```
loginctl unlock-session 1
```

Then I need to change back to terminal 1 (Ctrl-Alt-F1) again and the screen is unlocked, so that I'm back in Plasma.
What is wrong with the screen locker, with my procedure that my password is not recognized? Btw. I use SDDM as Display manager.